# upload pandas dataframe to BigQuery using to_gbq rewrites integer numbers

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I need to uploaded ~1000 dataframes to BigQuery, I'm using pandas.io.gbq.to_gbq

I have the code like this:

```
to_gbq(df, tableid, projectid, chunksize=10000, if_exists='append')
```

I am also writing all these dataframes to csv and the data all looks good, however, when uploading dfs to bigquery, for some of the dfs pandas just decides one of my integer column is float type, so I have this line of code to force pandas to read it as integer

```
df = df.astype({"ISBN": int})
```

Then I looked at the data pushed into BigQuery, the schema mismatch error is gone, but the numbers are all different to what they are in the CSV export (which I suppose is the same as in the original dataframe)...

For example, ISBN 9781607747307 in the CSV is now shown as 1967214315 in the BigQuery table

To troubleshoot, I printed out the dtype of dataframe, and noticed the above row is forcing the column to be INT64 dtype, whereas before the column that didn't go through the astype conversion has INT32 dtype.

Can I get pandas to see ISBN column as integer, but not change the numbers when upload to bigquery?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have any `NaNs` in that column? that would cause pandas to coerce to float.

Comment: @kyle don't think so. One of the schema mismatch error happened because the column has all 0 and pandas thinks the type is integer whereas in other dfs the column is float.